# Is there a proper name for order-independent data processing?

Tags: architecture, time-series, stream-processing

How do you call a (data processing) system where processing data in a different order does not alter the final result/state?

So that it can e.g. reprocess old data and arrive on the same results, without needing to process them in the exact order that they arrived at.

I thought of "order/time-independent" but looking if the industry has a name for this.

Comment: *Embarrassingly parallel* comes to mind; if you chase down its wiki page, it has pile of examples and related concepts.

Answer (score 1):

For event stream processing (at least in the context of distributed systems), it can called simply "Out-of-Order Data Processing", as in the title of the Dataflow Model paper by Google Research:

[The Dataflow Model: A Practical Approach to Balancing Correctness, Latency, and Cost in Massive-Scale, Unbounded, Out-of-Order Data Processing](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/43864.pdf)

Note that this refers to [Dataflow programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming), different from the [Dataflow architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_architecture) in Gerd's answer.

Depending on what problem you might be facing, it can be tackled with existing implementations of the Dataflow Model. You may also be interested in the [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/) project, a programming model heavily inspired in the Dataflow Model that can use a few underlying processing engines to perform the actual computation.

Existing processing systems using this model include:

- [Google Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow) (supported by Apache Beam)
- [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/) (supported by Apache Beam)
- [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the Flink community uses the term "event time processing" to refer to these cases where the results of a streaming computation are (nearly) deterministic regardless of the order in which events are processed.

Comment: Good point - this terminology is used in other "Dataflow-like" systems such as Google Cloud Dataflow itself, Beam, Kafka Streams, and others (though I didn't get around to mentioning this in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

In general, the result of a computing process *does* depend on the order of execution of processing steps (or instructions), simply because a processing step will often depend on the result of a previous step (see [data dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dependency)).

Now the computing system can try to automatically find these dependencies and schedule *independent* processing steps in a *different* order, which can happen either [at compile time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependence_analysis) or at runtime by using concepts such as [out-of-order execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution). Two (very old) methods that I am aware of are the [Tomasulo algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomasulo_algorithm) and [Scoreboarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoreboarding).

An entirely dfferent approach is a [dataflow architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_architecture), which however is rather used for some special applications and not in general-purpose systems.